# PHP regular expression start and end with given strings

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this 
`05/15/2015 09:19 PM pt_Product2017.9.abc.swl.px64_kor_7700` I need to select the `pt_Product2017.9.abc.swl.px64_kor` from that. (start with `pt_` and end with `_kor`)

```
$str = "05/15/2015 09:19 PM pt_Product2017.9.abc.swl.px64_kor_7700";
preg_match('/^pt_*_kor$/',$str, $matches);
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to remove the anchors, adda `\b` at the beginning to match `pt_` preceded with a non-word character, and use a `\S` with `*` (`\S` shorthand character class that matches any character but whitespace):

```
preg_match('/\bpt_\S*_kor/',$str, $matches);
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oR2lZ0/1)

In your regex,`^` and `$` force the regex engine to search for the `pt`at the beginning and `_kor` at the end of the string, and `_*` matches *0 or more underscores*. Note that *regex patterns* are not the same as *wildcards*.

In case there can be whitespace between `pt_` and `_kor`, use `.*`:

```
preg_match('/\bpt_.*_kor/',$str, $matches);
```

I should also mention greediness: if you have `pt_something_kor_more_kor`, the `.*`/`\S*` will match the whole string, but `.*?`/`\S*?` will match just `pt_something_kor`. Please adjust according to your requirements.

Comment: +1 I'm glad you modified this answer to explain why the regex is wrong, simply because it's going to be more useful to more people including OP.

Answer (score 1):

`^` and `$` are the start and end of the ***complete*** string, not only the matched one. So use simply `(pt_.+_kor)` to match everything between `pt_` and `_kor`: `preg_match('/(pt_+_kor)/',$str, $matches);`

Here's a demo: https://regex101.com/r/qL4fW9/1

Answer (score 1):

The `^` and `$` that you have used in the regular expression means that the string should *start* with `pt` AND *end* with `kor`. But it's neither starting as such, nor ending with `kor` (in fact, ending with `kor_7700`).

Try removing the `^` and `$`, and you'll get the match:

```
preg_match('/pt_.*_kor/',$str, $matches);
```